# service apache2 start causes error in django

Tags: python, apache2, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

On running

> apache2 configtest

**I get**

> Syntax error on line 2 of
> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/firstweb.conf: Invalid command
> 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
> included in the server configuration Action 'configtest' failed. The
> Apache error log may have more information.

**While**
On running

> apache2 -T

**I get**

> [Sat Nov 07 16:04:57.447763 2020] [core:warn] [pid 23334] AH00111:
> Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined apache2: Syntax error
> on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a
> valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot

I can't figure out the problem since I have installed mod_wsgi yet it is showing these errors. Any Idea?
*I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04*

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to check the apache config is

```
apachectl -t
```

Another way to correct this issue is setting the source of variables like this:

```
source /etc/apache2/envvars
```

(but this way you'l have to do this every time that you restart the server)